# Postgresql: join readonly database with csv-file

Tags: sql, postgresql, csv

The task is to join data from local cdv-file with data from remote database. On  this database I have readonly writes. So I can't create new tables in this db.

Only recommended way (which I have found) to do this is to: 1. Create new table in db 2. Copy (import) content of csv-file in this new table. 3. Make join between tables.

But I have no writes to create any tables in my database.

What another possible way solve this problem

Comment: If the database is really and truly read only then there is not much you can do on it. The only thing I think of it to create another Postgres instance nor database you can create/write to and use [postgres-fdw](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/postgres-fdw.html) to link to the read only database table and do the procedure you show in the database you can write to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot join with something that is not a database object, so you will **have to** create an object in the database.

The least invasive method is to use a [file_fdw](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/file-fdw.html) foreign table for the CSV file and join that with the table. Then you don't have to modify the foreign table definition if you modify the file.